# Changing the backgroundColor on individual events

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fullcalendar

I want to change the background color of individual events. The code is how I send the data to the events. The textColor seems to change but the color for backgroundColor or borderColor does not. What am I doing wrong or can the color be changed. I am using V 1

```
include("connect.php");
require_once("function.php");
$pid = $_SESSION['pid'];
$events = array();
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM `signings` WHERE `pid` = '$pid' AND `done`= 0") as $row) {
    $notaryid = $row['notayid'];
    $title = $row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'] . ' ' . $row['coname'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ' ' . $row['state'];
    $signstart = $row['signstart'] . ' ' . $row['starttime'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $ordern = $row['ordern'];
    $address = $row['street1'] . ' ' . $row['street2'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ', ' . $row['state'] . ', ' . $row['zip'];
    $hphone = 'Home Phone ' . $row['hphone'];
    $cphone = 'Cell Phone ' . $row['cphone'];
    $wphone = 'Work Phone ' . $row['wphone'];
    $custid = $row['custid'];

    $sql1 = "Select name from customers WHERE custid = '$custid'";
    $stmt1 = $db->query($sql1);
    $row1 = $stmt1->fetchObject();
    $name = $row1->name;  


    $sql2 = "Select firstname,lastname,color from notarys WHERE nid = '$notaryid'";
    $stmt2 = $db->query($sql2);
    $row2 = $stmt2->fetchObject();
    $colors = $row2->color;
    $notary = $row2->firstname . " " . $row2->lastname;


    $eventsArray['id'] = $id;
    $eventsArray['ordern'] = $ordern;
    $eventsArray['title'] = $title . ' ' . $name;
    $eventsArray['start'] = $signstart;
    $eventsArray['date1'] = phpdatetimeam($signstart);
    $eventsArray['address'] = $address;
    $eventsArray['hphone'] = $hphone;
    $eventsArray['cphone'] = $cphone;
    $eventsArray['wphone'] = $wphone;
    $eventsArray['notary'] = $notary;
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = "";
    $eventsArray['color'] = $colors;   <-- This is were I change the color
    $eventsArray['textColor'] = "#FFFFFF"; I have tried backgroundColor and
                                 BorderColor but now of them work
    $events[] = $eventsArray;
}


echo json_encode($events);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line after your foreach you have a misspelling:

```
$notaryid = $row['notayid'];
```

Should be:

```
$notaryid = $row['notaryid'];
```

I don't know if that is an issue or not, I'm trying to see where you are setting the background color in your events array, i only see the text color which is the last element of your array.

Comment: The background color is just above the textcolor right now in this code I have color bur I have also used  backgroundColor

Comment: I fixed the misspelling and it works now. I can't believe I missed that. Been going over the peace of code for a week but did not see that.